# One-sided incompressible surface in 3-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Let $M^3$ be a closed orientable $3$-manifold. If $H_2(M,\mathbb Z)=0$ and $H_2(M, \mathbb Z_2)\ne 0$, can we show that $M$ contains a 1-sided incompressible surface?

Comment: What is the definition of 1-sided incompressible surface? Is $P^2\times \{x\}$ incompressible inside $P^2 \times S^1$?

Comment: @BrunoMartelli A surface is 1-sided if its normal bundle in the ambient 3-manifold is not trivial. $P^2 \times {x}$ is incompressible in $P^2 \times S^1$.

Answer (score 3):

This follows from two exercises.

**Exercise 1**. Every class in $H_2(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ is represented by a smooth embedded surface.  (See Exercise 4.5.12(b) in "4-Manifolds and Kirby Calculus" by Gompf and Stipsicz.)

Suppose that the surface is $S \subset M$.  If $S$ is orientable, then it bounds modulo $\mathbb{Z}$ and thus modulo $\mathbb{Z}_2$, a contradiction.  Thus $S$ is not orientable.  Since $M$ is orientable, any such surface is one-sided.  We now "compress".

**Exercise 2.** Compressing a surface does not change the homology class represented.  If the compression separates, then at least one component will be non-trivial in $H_2(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ and so will again be one-sided. (See the proof of Lemma 6.3 of "3-manifolds" by Hempel for a very similar technique.)

Thus we eventually arrive at the desired one-sided incompressible surface.

Comment: Non-orientable does not imply odd Euler characteristic, but you don't need that to deduce that it is 1-sided. On the other hand, I am a bit confused on the definition of incompressible surface in the 1-sided setting.

Comment: I see. The surface $S$ obtained in Ex.1 is nonorientable and 1-sided since $M$ is orientable. If $S=P^2$, then we are done by Ex.2. If $S$ is compressible, one can do surgery along the compressing disk to obtain a new surface $S'$ with $\chi(S') \ge \chi(S)+1$. Eventually one obtains an incompressible surface.

Comment: @BrunoMartelli - ah, my brain skipped a beat.  It is fixed now.

Comment: @BrunoMartelli - Hempel writes out a careful definition of incompressible on page 58 of his book.  I think of it as follows.  Suppose that $(M, F)$ is a pair, with $M$ a closed three-manifold and $F$ a closed surface embedded in $M$.  Then a "surgery disk" for $(M, F)$ is an embedding of pairs $(D, \partial D) \subset (M, F)$.  If $\partial D$ is essential in $F$ then the surgery is "essential" and we have a "compression" etc.

Comment: A compression can turn a 1-sided surface into a 2-sided surface, eg. think about the Klein bottle in $S^2\times S^1$.

Comment: Here $S$ is non-separating. After compressing as much as possible, some component will be incompressible and non-separating. That component cannot be 2-sided since $H_2(M;\mathbb{Z})=0$.

Comment: @JoshHowie - Ok, this time I was not wrong, exactly... I have clarified.